# Bounding $\text{Var}[X+Y]$ as a function of $\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance, variance, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X, Y$ be two real-valued random variables.
We have that 
$$COV(X,Y)\le \sqrt{\text{Var}[X]\text{Var}[Y]}\le\max\{\text{Var}[X],\text{Var}[Y]\}\le\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y].$$

This allows us to write:
$$
\text{Var}[X+Y] = \text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y] + 2COV(X,Y)\le 3(\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]).
$$

This seems like a very crude bound. Is there a way to improve it? 
Since I'm only interested in bounding it as a function of $\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$, I'll phrase the question as:

> **What is the smallest constant $c$ such that $\text{Var}[X+Y]\le c\cdot (\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y])$ for any two random variables $X,Y$**?

---

By setting $X=Y$, we have $\text{Var}[X+Y]=\text{Var}[2X]=4\text{Var}[X]=2(\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y])$ so we have $2\le c\le 3$. What is the correct answer?

Comment: The fact that $c=2$ works is just a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Note that covariance defines an inner product on $L^2$ random variables modulo constants. Now the desired bound just says that $$\|x+y\|^2 \leq 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$$ which is equivalent to Cauchy-Schwarz in any inner product space over $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**$c=2$ works.** *(as in the case $(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2+b^2)$ of squares.)*

Note that, assuming without loss of generality for the proof that $\mathbb{E}[X]= \mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] &= \mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2]\\
&=  \mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]+2\mathbb{E}[XY] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]+\left(\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2] \right)\tag{AM-GM}\\
&= 2\left(\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]\right)\\
&= 2\left(\operatorname{Var}[X]+\operatorname{Var}[Y]\right)
\end{align}$$
where te [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) was used to write
$$
\mathbb{E}[XY]\leq \mathbb{E}\!\left[\frac{X^2+Y^2}{2}\right]\,.
$$

Comment: Just a note for @RB. AM-GM inequality implies $COV(X,Y) = \sqrt{Var(X)Var(y)} \le \frac{Var(X)+Var(Y)}{2}$.

Comment: @MathLover with an inequality first, but yes.